# Run Docker container on host network

Tags: docker, macvlan

I'd like to assign a static IP to a `docker container` and have it work like a virtual machine on the host network.

Example:

Network of 10.10.10.0/24

Physical host running Docker IP: 10.10.10.1

Docker container IP: 10.10.10.2

Now obviously that's rather easy as long as I have a separate NIC for the container - otherwise there's problems with ARP. I have read up on `macvlan` networks and they seem to be a way to resolve this:

https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/

However, it says clearly says that:

> In this case, you need to designate a physical interface on your
>   Docker host to use for the Macvlan, as well as the subnet and gateway
>   of the Macvlan.

Can this physical interface still carry a "normal" IP address so it can communicate with other physical hosts on the network?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can.

By default though there will be no connectivity from host to a container. [Official doc for v17.09](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/#macvlan-bridge-mode-example-usage) states the following:

> When using macvlan, you cannot ping or communicate with the default
> namespace IP address. For example, if you create a container and try
> to ping the Docker host’s eth0, it will not work. That traffic is
> explicitly filtered by the kernel modules themselves to offer
> additional provider isolation and security.
>
> A macvlan subinterface can be added to the Docker host, to allow
> traffic between the Docker host and containers. The IP address needs
> to be set on this subinterface and removed from the parent address.

While that version of docker might be old the manual for it had a number of useful commands that were removed in the newer docs:

> On Debian or Ubuntu, adding the following to /etc/network/interfaces will make this persistent.

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual

auto mac0
iface mac0 inet dhcp
  pre-up ip link add mac0 link eno1 type macvlan mode bridge
  post-down ip link del mac0 link eno1 type macvlan mode bridge
```

NOTE: Make sure you are not using Ubuntu's netplan that was introduced in v18 to manage those interfaces.